# EntityContext throwing "not marked as serializable" in UnitOfWork Pattern using State Server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Background is ASP.NET WebForms application using Entity Framework with Repository and UnitOfWork pattern.  Note that the application is also configured to use the out-of-proc StateServer for Session mgt which I understand means that anything I store in session must be serializable.

I also have an HttpModule configured to create a UnitOfWork object (which contains my entity context object) upon each HttpRequest, store it in HttpContext.Current.Items, and of course dispose it at the end of each request.

My UnitOfWork class itself contains properties for each of my repositories as well as the entity context itself.

In an effort to allow more flexible testing in the future, I created an IObjectContext interface with signatures for the methods and properties on my entity context, and I created a partial class for my entity context and inherited from it.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IObjectContext context;
}
public UnitOfWork(IObjectContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}


public partial class MyEntities : IObjectContext
{
}


private static void ApplicationBeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("UnitOfWork"))
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("UnitOfWork", unitOfWork);
    }
}

private void ApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["UnitOfWork"] != null)
        ((IUnitOfWork)HttpContext.Current.Items["UnitOfWork"]).Dispose();
}
```

The goal here is ultimately to allow me to fake my entity context object to create for example, an in-memory context for testing purposes.

Everything was going fine until I started getting "not marked as serializable" exceptions on my entity context object.  Obviously my first thought was to just add [Serializable] to my partial entity context class, but then it started complaining that System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext in Assembly System.Data.Entity was not marked as serializable (which I obviously don't have any control over).

What am I missing here?  It seems like I can't store my entity context object in HttpContext.Current.Items, which I must do for my unit of work pattern implementation.

Is this because I'm using the ASP.NET State Server instead of in-proc session mgt?  Surely there's a way to store the context for the life of the HTTP request if you're using the State Server?

Just feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I've added [Serializable] to everything from the UnitOfWork to the MyEntities context to each repository class.  Still can't get past the entity context itself.

Any ideas?

UPDATE (Adding Stack Trace):

```
[SerializationException: Type 'myDAL.Model.myEntities' in Assembly 'myDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
 System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +14324629
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +408
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +420
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +532
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +969
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +633
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +322
System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1487

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.]
System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +2485899
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +49
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer) +746
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream) +336
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean compressionEnabled) +99
 System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +3828904
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +1021
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It definitely looks like this is caused by an object in the session not in the request context. Are you sure you do not store your data objects in the session?

Comment: well, there are a couple of other objects (user details, etc) stored in session as part of the application but my unit of work (and therefore the object context) is stored in the HttpContext.Current.Items (code added to question above).

Comment: you sir, are 100% correct.  I got to digging through the user object that *is* being stored in session and it turns out I'd inadvertently cached a private copy of the unitofwork within the user object itself.  once i removed the private property, it worked perfectly.  if you'll post your comment about it being in session as an answer, i'll gladly give you credit.  thanks again-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that there is a non-serializable object in the *session*, not in the context. Double check that you did not put your data object in session by mistake.

Putting it into the context request should not be giving this error.